# How to bind multi-field values in clips using readline

Tags: explode, clips

I want to assign a multifield template in CLIPS with readline and explode$.
However I dont know how to do it. I am beginner in CLIPS.

```
?input <-  (explode$ (readline))
(modify ?input (command (first ?input)) (argument (second ?input)))
(assert ?input ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (deftemplate command (slot first) (slot second))
CLIPS> 
(defrule example
   =>
   (printout t "Input? ")
   (bind ?input (explode$ (readline)))
   (assert (command (first (nth$ 1 ?input)) 
                    (second (nth$ 2 ?input)))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Input? red green
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (command (first red) (second green))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```